# Kernel compiling errors?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel

I'm trying to install kernel in Ubuntu 18.10 and alongside the way while compiling it, I ran into some errors having to do with Make File build i think, I have searched about these errors but i couldn't find any particular solution for them, so I decided to show the errors in here hoping that someone can help me out.

[image: errors shown in the picture]
[image: these errors are stopping the compile to be completed]

Comment: On Stack Overflow we want error message to be in the question post itself **as text**, not as image. Please, [edit] the question post and add into it textual representation of the errort. BTW, the reason of your problem is written in the error message: "out of memory".

Comment: How can i give a textual representation for something that i don’t know much about, i’d love to but i couldn’t, if you or anyone else actually tried to help rather than explaining me the site rules, wouldn’t that be something?

Comment: I meant pasting text from the terminal instead of pasting screenshots. Site rules exist not just for themselves, they give a guide how to create a question which can be answered by larger audience and can be useful for larger audience. By posting images instead of text you lose possible answerers, which do not like to re-type error messages from the screenshots to search engine. As for the problem itself, see the last sentence of the my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Linux has an auto-protection mechanism which is called Oom Killer.
If a processus endangers the whole system by taking too much memory, it is killed.

As it seems you're in a VM, allocate more RAM and that should do it.
If it's not possible, try configure Oom killer.

Comment: I’m giving more ram memory but then its going way slow